# .htaccess rewrite url - show html file as jpg

Tags: html, image, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have image.html and I want It to be shown in browser as image.jpg, because there are some operations when showing picture, that can't be done before or after. Is it even possible with .htaccess and url rewriting?

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^image\.html$ image.jpg
```

but without any luck.

Thanks for all answers

Comment: I'm wondering whether I understand your question right. Are you asking if a given HTML file can be magically rendered to a JPEG because of a regular expression in your webserver changing the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need let's say a PHP script. Call it `image.php`. After that, use a GET parameter to handle the image name. Let's call it `name`. To call a picture you need `image.php?name=allo`.

Now. In the PHP script, you need to specify in the header it's an image, JPEG. Required. After that, just "print" the picture within the page.

All you need after is Rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^image\.php?name=(.*)$ /images_jpeg/$1
```

The header is really important. This is why it doesn't work with an HTML file.

Comment: I only want the file show with extension *.jpg (like when you show php files as php), but i want html to interpret.